# CSS ::first-line selector Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors

I have an issue with the ::first-line selector in Chrome. In Firefox and even IE11 the result looks correct.

- Here is what I expect it to be: [Rendered in Firefox/IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdo3F.png)
- Here is what I get in Chrome: [Rendered in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbrNO.png)

But there is a weird behaviour in Chrome which results in a correct rendering:

- open the developer panel (F12)
- select the "t1b" item
- untick the "box-shadow" property
- tick it again

Here is a link to an example: [jsfiddle.net/smc0hx78/](https://jsfiddle.net/smc0hx78)

```
<body>
<span class="test">t1</span>
<span class="test firstLine">t1b</span>
<span class="test"><span>t2</span></span>
</body>

body {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.test {
  width: 2.5em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 50px -50px 0 0 cyan;
}
.test span {
  font-size: 13px;
}
.firstLine::first-line {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

- "t1" has no "first-line" (working fine in Chrome)
- "t1b" has "first-line" (not working in Chrome)
- "t2" has "first-line" but for a sub element (working fine in Chrome)

I need t1b to be working in Chrome.

1. Do I have any error in my CSS?
2. Is there a workaround without a sub element?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `display: inline-flex` instead of `inline-block` seems to be working fine, but it looks like a bug in Chrome for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Chromium Bug, though I have not found anything like that in the Github Issues (still, it could be resolved in a future release)

You have two options:

1 - Add an empty div before your spans. It seems to work if you put an empty block-element before your inline-blocks (don't know why)

```
<body>
<div></div>
<span class="test">t1</span>
<span class="test firstLine">t1b</span>
<span class="test"><span>t2</span></span>
</body>
```

or 2 - Change inline-block to inline-flex. The bug seems to affect only inline-blocks

```
.test {
  display: inline-block; /* OLD */
  display: inline-flex; /* NEW */
}
```

Comment: the `inline-flex` looks ok at first glance but the `first-line` selector gets ignored in that case. "t1" and "t1b" do not have a font size of `13px`.

The `<div>` workaround is very weird but it seems to be working.
I have no sub element (only a sibling) which is fine to me.

Thanks for the help.